# Как правильно вычислить дату в sql запросе?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть задача, сделать выборку в таблице по возрасту - до ЛЕТ. Дата рождения хранится в типе поля date. 
Пытаюсь сделать так (25 лет для примера):

```
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 25 YEAR) <= birth
```

Но проблема в том, что если у человека прошел возраст на 1 день больше, то ему все равно 25 лет, но он уже не попадает в список. Как можно сделать с ориентировкой именно на ГОД ?

Comment: до 25 - это означает, что человеку должно быть максимум 24 года. Если всё же нужно включить возраст 25, то почему бы в запросе не выставить 26?

Answer (score 2):

Есть [ответ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-calculations.html) в официальной документации:

```
    SELECT birth, CURDATE(),
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birth,CURDATE()) AS age
           FROM your_table
           WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birth,CURDATE()) <= 25
```

Answer (score -1):

Мне лично считать удобнее так:

```
select * from t where year(curdate) - year(birth) < yourvalue
;
```

**update**

Я не знаком с MySQL совсем, но такой вариант работает в других БД

```
select * from t where year(curdate - birth) < yourvalue
;
```

Comment: В этом случае не учитывается месяц и день рождения. То есть независимо от этого всем пользователям с наступлением нового года прибавится 1 год, но это не совсем корректно.